# How to get current date and time in Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: datetime, yahoo-pipes

Is there a way to get current date and time in Yahoo Pipes?

I need this to create a pipe with only the newest questions from SO as I don't want to wait for SO team to implement RSS for this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The Date Builder module converts a
>   text string into a datetime value. You
>   can pick a date using the handy
>   built-in calendar widget, enter a text
>   string into the module's entry field,
>   or wire a string into it from another
>   module, like the Text Input module.
>
> Date Builder understands all the date
>   formats as Date Input, formats like
>   "tomorrow" and "3 days ago", as well
>   as "07/04/2007" and "16:32 EST".
>
> This module is useful when you need to
>   extract items from a feed by date. In
>   this example, we'll use the U.S. CERT
>   computer security Atom feed. This feed
>   provides information on computer
>   vulnerabilities reported in the last
>   few months.
>  In our example, we
>   want to return only very recent items,
>   problems reported in the last five
>   days.

Source: [Yahoo! Pipes Module Reference: Date Modules](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=date#DateBuilder)

Answer (score 4):

For what you want to do, using the DateBuilder module with syntax like '-24 hours' would probably be best.

I've created a [demo pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=650e11e9002bcd8637641c9559a9ec3f) that fetches stories from Slashdot from the last 24 hours as an example. For some more info about the various kinds of syntax supported, [see here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=user_inputs#Date).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the DateBuilder with a string of "today" - to get the current date/time or "today 12:00 UTC" to just a date with no time